# Render to texture problems

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo

I'm tyring to get rendering to texture working, but am having a bit of trouble. I'm trying to render a simple quad to the screen to make sure everything is working.

```
    target->enable();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor4f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glVertex3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    glColor4f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glVertex3f(16.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    glColor4f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    glVertex3f(0.f, 16.f, 0.f);

    glColor4f(1.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glVertex3f(16.f, 16.f, 0.f);

    glEnd();

    target->disable();
```

When I draw the quad to the screen normally, the quad renders as expected. However, when I draw the quad with the render target enabled, the quad gets rendered at the bottom left corner of the screen and ends up not being rendered to the target.

```
RenderTarget::RenderTarget(GraphicsDevice *graphics, GLuint width, GLuint height) {

    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;

    // First create the depth buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &mDepth);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, mDepth);

    // Tell OpenGL that this renderbuffer is going to be a depth buffer
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, mWidth, mHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, mDepth);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, 0);

    // Create the frame buffer texture
    glGenTextures(1, &mTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mWidth, mHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // Create the frame buffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &mFbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, mFbo);

    // Attach the texture
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture, 0);

    //Attach the depth buffer
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, mFbo);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);


}

RenderTarget::~RenderTarget() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &mFbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &mDepth);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &mTexture);
    mFbo = 0;
    mDepth = 0;
    mTexture = 0;
}

void RenderTarget::enable() {
    // Bind the frame buffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, mFbo);
    // store the glViewport and glEnable states
    //glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT);

    glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    glLoadIdentity();
}

void RenderTarget::disable() {
    // Restore glViewport and glEnable states
    glPopAttrib();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
}
```

Comment: Is your FBO [complete](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness)?  You don't seem to be calling `glCheckFramebufferStatus()`.

Comment: Yea, came back with GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your enable is resetting the current matrix (most likely modelview) with `glLoadIdentity`. This explains why your square is being moved to the corner of the screen.

You've commented out the call to `glPushAttrib` but not the matching call to `glPopAttrib`. If you don't use `glPushAttrib` anywhere else this should set an error flag and leave GL state alone, but I don't know that's the case and it's asking for trouble to assume that the attribute stack is and always will be empty.

**[This](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glBindFramebuffer.xml)** documentation for `glBindFrameBuffer` suggests that you ought to be using `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` or `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` as the first argument:

> `target` must be either GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER or
>   GL_FRAMEBUFFER. If a framebuffer object is bound to
>   GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER or GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, it becomes the target for
>   rendering or readback operations, respectively, until it is deleted or
>   another framebuffer is bound to the corresponding bind point. Calling
>   `glBindFramebuffer` with target set to GL_FRAMEBUFFER binds `framebuffer`
>   to both the read and draw framebuffer targets.

The enums with _EXT suffix in your code likely pertain to a version of OpenGL previous to the version documented there. Tutorials are prone to allowing details like this to fall out of date.

Check your environment & rely on the documentation that matches your version of OpenGL. If for some reason you can't easily determine your version of OpenGL, check for the GL_INVALID_ENUM error after calling `glBindFrameBuffer`.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems wrong:

```
//Attach the depth buffer
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, mFbo);
```

What you are doing here is that you are trying to attach mFbo as a render buffer to mFbo. However, you already have your render buffer attached correctly (which is done in the first call to glFramebufferRenderbuffer()). I think removing that code should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, my problem was setting glViewport, and glOrtho correctly when rendering the FBO. This code needs to be cleaned up, but here is how I fixed it.

```
void RenderTarget::enable() {
    // Bind the frame buffer

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, mFbo);
    // store the glViewport and glEnable states
    //glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
    // projection matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // orthographic projection
    glOrtho(0, mWidth, 0, mHeight, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    glLoadIdentity();
}

void RenderTarget::disable() {
    // Restore glViewport and glEnable states
    //glPopAttrib();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // orthographic projection
    glOrtho(0, 1024, 768, 0, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Comment: In the code I posted above, I reset Matrix mode back to it's normal settings manually. Is there a way to do this by pushing/poping to the stack? I tried glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix, but that didn't seem to work as I would expect

Comment: `glPushAttrib` with the `GL_TRANSFORM_BIT` will save the matrix mode, along with some other state. Check documentation for the details.